# What boostrap element can I use to make a mobile help site

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need help finding a good solution for a help section for my iOS app.  On a previous app, I've tried doing an in-app help section.  This was really difficult to maintain because whenever a new problem came up, I would have to update the app for that one problem.  Although a UITableView looks nice and native, I would like to use a mobile-optimized website for my next app.

The problem is, I can't find something good to use!  I don't mind paying monthly for a help-desk like service that is hosted on another company's servers, but I'm starting to think I should make a custom solution.

I like twitter's bootstrap, so I am going to try to use it to create a mobile help page.  The problem is, I would have no idea how to customize it to make it look and feel like a smooth UITableView.  I don't want it to look exactly like it, but I want to at least have section headers.  By section headers, I mean rather large rectangles that have the same width as the screen, and whenever you touch them, a help section smoothly appears below it.  Is there an existing bootstrap element that can do something like this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ButtonGroups http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#buttonGroups with the vertical arrangement set to get the look you want.

e.g. it could/would look something like this:

[image]

Side note: the screenshot is from a PC desktop... the buttons are set to "span3" you can make them as wide as desired etc. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical">
        <button class="btn span3">Topic ABC</button>
        <button class="btn span3">Topic DEF</button>
        <button class="btn span3">Topic GHI</button>
        <button class="btn span3">Topic JKL</button>
        <button class="btn span3">Topic MNO</button>
        <button class="btn span3">Topic PQR</button>
        <button class="btn span3">Topic STU</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting!  And I would just then use jQuery to make content appear when tapped?

Comment: sure thing... or even inline events if it makes it easier.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this for the UI